# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laragon

**Este es el Error al querer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException

```
 SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Comment: cual podria ser el error?

Comment: Revisa si lo que se publicó aquí te sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807717/how-can-i-solve-postgresql-scram-authentifcation-problem

Comment: el problema radica, en que soy nuevo en esto, no se como actualizar el archivo libpq, si tiene un ejemplo de como actualizar, me seria de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Yo tenía el mismo problema y me sucedió porque cambié a una versión actualizada de **PostgreSql** la cual usa un metodo de encriptación distinta.

Lo solucioné cambiando en el archivo ***postgresql.conf***:

```
password_encryption = md5
```

Luego en el archivo ***pg_hba.conf***:

```
METHOD = md5
```

Reinicie PostgreSQL

Cambie la contraseña del usuario que estaba usando para conectarme en postgresql

Una vez hecho esto ya me funcionó sin problemas.

Saludos.

Comment: Pero eso no soluciona el problema, estás cambiando la encriptación de postgres